# How to get the position where columns differ

Tags: r

I want to know at which position the columns differ, are not identical. The identical function tell the columns are not identical but how do I know where? Good to know in a bigger dataset!

```
a <- c(4,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,3,5)
b <- c(4,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,2,3,5)

df <- data.frame(id,a,b)
identical(df$a,df$b)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare two columns and use `which` to get position

```
which(df$a != df$b)
#[1] 3
```